# MC Simulation using G2Process Evolve function

Tags: monte-carlo, quantlib

I am trying to simulate the IR for G2 Process using the following code. However, the initial value of the simulation starts with zero. I want to initialize the simulation using a starting value.
Is there any way that I can do this?
Also, in this code, the final value of the simulation is 0 (Starting value). However, it should be the last simulated value. Where am I going wrong?

The code is:

```
    timestep = 360
    length = 30  # in years

    g2_process = ql.G2Process(a, sigma, b, eta, rho)

    num_paths = 200
    grid = ql.TimeGrid(length, timestep)
    rng = ql.GaussianRandomSequenceGenerator(ql.UniformRandomSequenceGenerator(2, 
    ql.UniformRandomGenerator()))


    def generate_paths(num_paths, timestep):
    dz = ql.Array(2, 0.0)
    path = np.zeros(shape=(num_paths, timestep + 1))
    sample = ql.Array(2, 0.0)
    for i in range(num_paths):
        ir = ql.Array(2, 0.0)

    for j in range(timestep):
        ir = g2_process.evolve(grid[j], ir, grid.dt(j), dz)
        sample = rng.nextSequence().value()
        dz[0] = sample[0]
        dz[1] = sample[1]
        path[i, j] = np.sum(ir)
time = np.array([grid[j] for j in range(len(grid))])
return time, path
```